# Eclipse Project Ideas

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an Eclipse plugin project that produce an another perspective as OUTPUT. Here which Class/File(.exe) file should be given to the Clients for their access? Because we won't give the entire coding into them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an Eclipse plugin the output is **always** a plugin jar file which you create using 'Export > Plug-in Development > Deployable plug-ins and fragments'

This plugin will only contain class files and not your source code.

Comment: Yeah i already tried this one,but it generate an error like "THE ANT TASKS GENERated files can be found at--e:

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you are doing and what is going wrong.

Comment: Yup Sure.,Am create an eclipse plugin project that produce an output as another perspective window in the eclipse console window.,The problem is when i need to give my project to the clients,it must be in .EXE format.,and also import the plugin created by me.,how can i do it.,?EXPORT>ADDING FRAGMENTS method fails.,can u say any other suggestion